# Javascript/Coffeescript append TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Why isn't working?

It works if I change variable msg for a string value.

Code:

```
console.log full_messages # Array [ "text to be displayed" ]
for msg in full_messages
  $('#error_explanation ul').append('<li>'+ msg +'</li>')
```

Error message:

> TypeError: msg is not a function

Comment: @tholo Did you mean about this "$ ->". If yes! yes, it is.

Comment: `full_massages[msg]`

Comment: $('#error_explanation ul').append('<li>'+ full_messages[0] +'</li>') - this didn't work too (without iteration)

Comment: See my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your whitespace (or lack thereof):

```
'<li>'+ msg +'</li>'
```

CoffeeScript thinks that the second `+` in that is a unary operator so the whole thing is interpreted as:

```
'<li>' + msg(+'</li>')
```

If you put spaces on both sides of your binary operators:

```
'<li>' + msg + '</li>'
#     ^^^   ^^^
```

then CoffeeScript does what you're expecting it to. **Rule of Thumb**: always put spaces on both sides of binary operators.

You could also use string interpolation:

```
"<li>#{msg}</li>"
```

That becomes exactly the same JavaScript as `'<li>' + msg + '</li>'` but is (arguably) more readable and idiomatic.

Comment: Nice man! I knew that the problem was something stupid! And very nice the tip about interpolation!

Comment: You're welcome, I've internalized so many little formatting "rules" that it took me a bit to figure out what was wrong.